# Running time analysis of a linear algorithm seems to me quadratic

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, runtime-analysis

I have been analyzing an algorithm for several hours in order to find out why it is expressed as $O(n)$ (I saw this solution in a PowerPoint presentation which refers to it as a *linear algorithm*). I see a `while`  loop inside a `for` loop.

The `for` loop executes $n$ times.

The `while` loop executes "at most" $n$ times $(0, 1, 2, ..., n - 1)$ which can be represented as $n*(n+1)/2$

So, the running time formula can be $(n)*[n*(n+1)/2]$ which yields to a quadratic expression. (I have not taken into account individual statements inside the loops for simplicity).

What is wrong with my reasoning?

`Algorithm spans2(X, n)
    S = new array of n integers
    A = new empty stack
    for i = 0 to n - 1 do
        while (!A.isEmpty() && X[A.top()] <= X[i] ) do
            A.pop()
        if A.isEmpty() then
            S[i] = i + 1
        else
            S[i] = i - A.top()
        A.push(i)
    return S`

Comment: *not related to time-complexity:* What is purpose of this algo? Where is it used? Looks like for each element of array it's calculate closest number on the left that is bigger.

Answer (score 3):

Inner while loop will be executed at most $L$ times, where $L$ is number of integers that will be added to stack $A$, and it will be at most $N$ pushes to stack, because `A.push(i)` is called in outer for loop, so body of inner while loop (`A.pop()`) will be executed at most $N$ times.

Comment: Does it mean that the $A.pop()$ operation inside the $while$ is not taken into account? There is a variation of this algorithm in which $A.pop()$ is replaced with $j=A.pop()$. Is the analysis still the same?

Comment: The pop operation is actually why, over all iterations of the outer loop, the inner loop will be executed at most $L$ times in total.

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis is *too coarse*; cf. also the analysis of Dijkstra's algorithm. You find $O(n^2)$ (due to saying "at most" and ignoring constant factors) which is a valid upper bound, but it is a bad one.

If you look closer, you can show an $O(n)$ upper bound; together with a trivial $\Omega(n)$ lower bound (from the `for` loop alone) you get $\Theta(n)$ asymptotic runtime, i.e. linear.
One way to do this is to [count how often every statement is executed](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/23595/98).

Here are the relevant observations:

- Ever iteration of the `for` loop pushes exactly one element to the stack.
- The `while` loop has at most one iteration for every element ever on the stack.

Combine these observations with what you already know, write up your [statement counts](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/23595/98) and obtain the result.